# Disclosing a proposal

Tags: research-proposal

My PI forwarded to me the proposal of a project I have to work on. Recently, a new postdoc arrived and he is supposed to write a  proposal by himself. He asked me to forward the one I received from my PI. The issue is that I am not sure if I should disclose it without having explicitly PI's authorization. This person told me that PI was OK with it (but I wasn't  present at that meeting). Am I being too paranoid?.

My rationale behind this is that I shouldn't be forwarding something I didn't write to anyone unless the author says is fine with it. Besides, this is an ongoing project... In any case, I have already written to PI to have his authorization, but meanwhile, it is uncomfortable to deal with the other person. I would like to know your opinions about this. Thanks.

Comment: I read the first paragraph three times, and I don't understand it at all.  I would suggest rewriting it with more care to explaining the details of your situation.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I have updated it. Is it better now?.

Comment: So this person told you specifically that your PI OK'ed this but you don't believe him? I would've just sent it to him anyways, and assuming this is through email, copied your advisor. Maybe write a line making it clear that you thought this was according to your PIs instructions. I don't see any reason to doubt his words though tbh.. and sharing proposals is (or should be) very common

Comment: @ConfusedStudent007 When I was working in another institution I was told to never disclose anything about proposals/research plans without PI's explicit ack. What you wrote makes sense (and it is very practical), just CC PI and that's it.

Comment: @muammar: Yes, much better.

Comment: Since you asked your PI already I don't see any point in asking here - the answer only depends on the specific PI and there is no general rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell the other student as many times as necessary that you just need the okay directly from the PI and then you'll be happy to forward it.

I would try to steer the PI away from okaying the forward.  It would be different if you already knew and trusted this individual.

The germ of an idea for a project can be very important.  This is your baby and I understand your wanting to protect it.

(You need not explain that to the other student.)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I don't think PI will take it bad. As I mentioned in another comment, in another research institution I worked, these things were very delicate.